# Oracle JET Error: Missing folder 'oraclejet-tooling/hooks/'

Tags: android, oracle, oracle-jet

I am trying to build a hybrid application using oracle jet framework. In this attempt i am trying to run it as an android app. I have gone through the per-requisists as mentioned in their document and when i gave this command in terminal it gave me this result

```
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-Edge-E431:~/OrJetWork$ npm list -g --depth=0
/usr/lib
├── cordova@7.0.1
├── generator-oraclejet@3.0.0
├── grunt-cli@1.2.0
├── npm@4.6.1
└── yo@1.8.5
```

and for  oracle get-yeomen generator

```
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-Edge-E431:~/OrJetWork$ npm list -g generator-oraclejet
/usr/lib
└── generator-oraclejet@3.0.0
```

also i have set ANDROID_HOME, and path etc which points to my Android studio's corresponding folders

but when i tried to run this command as mentioned in the tutorial

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet300/jet/developer/GUID-C75CD8DC-5084-4831-BE1A-FFEE4EA8600C.htm#JETDG-GUID-67A23ACD-73AD-45B8-8F44-D3501B9A8F24

i am getting this error.

```
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-Edge-E431:~/OrJetWork$ yo oraclejet:hybrid app --appname="Sample NavBar" --template=navbar --platform=android
Processing template... navbar
Creating a new cordova project.
Adding platform : android
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.2.2
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: org.oraclejet.app
    Name: Sample_NavBar
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-25
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.2.3
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

               This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.

Adding cordova-plugin-whitelist to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-whitelist" to config.xml
--save flag or autosave detected
Saving android@~6.2.3 into config.xml file ...
Adding platform : browser
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-browser@~4.1.0
Adding browser project...
Running command: /home/mukund/OrJetWork/app/hybrid/node_modules/cordova-browser/bin/create /home/mukund/OrJetWork/app/hybrid/platforms/browser org.oraclejet.app "Sample NavBar"
Creating Browser project. Path: platforms/browser
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for browser
--save flag or autosave detected
Saving browser@~4.1.0 into config.xml file ...
Oracle JET: Your app structure is generated. Continuing with library install...
Performing npm install may take a bit...
Invoking npm install
npm WARN Invalid name: "Sample NavBar"
npm WARN app No description
npm WARN app No repository field.
npm WARN app No README data
npm WARN app No license field.
Error oraclejet:hybrid app --appname=Sample NavBar --template=navbar --platform=android 

Oracle JET Error: Missing folder 'oraclejet-tooling/hooks/'.
```

I dont know what i am missing here. Please help

Answer (score 3):

Drop the

```
--appname="Sample NavBar"
```

part and things should work, it was a bug.

It's fixed in JET 4.0, which introduces the "ojet" replacement for "yo" to scaffold the project. (though you can still use the yo/grunt as well)

So uninstall the old generator:

```
npm uninstall -g generator-oraclejet
```

then

```
npm install -g @oracle/generator-oraclejet
```

or

```
npm install -g @oracle/ojet-cli
```

Then try:

```
ojet create app1 --hybrid --appname="Sample Navbar" --template=navbar --platform=android
```

or the old style:

```
yo @oracle/oraclejet:hybrid app1 --appname="Sample NavBar" --template=navbar --platform=android
```

works fine.